# Can I plug a new router into an existing router to use a different security protocol?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, internet-connection

My college's WiFi uses a security protocol that many of my devices (Smart TV, 3DS, Wii, and smart lights) have trouble connecting to. There is also a guest network but it's very slow and very unstable, often my devices report an "unknown error" when trying to use it. Luckily each dorm room has its own WiFi router with active Ethernet ports, so I was wondering if I could buy a cheap travel router (right now I'm looking at the GL.iNet GL-AR750 since it's on sale), plug it into the existing router, and set up my own network. If I did this, would I be able to set up my own more standard security protocol?

Just in case it's helpful, here are my internet speeds in mb/s:

- Guest WiFi: 1.6 down & 3.5 up
- Secure WiFI: 25.2 down & 162.2 up
- Ethernet Cable: 817.4 down & 929.2 up

Thank you for your help and sorry of this is a stupid question that I'm overthinking!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

You could connect your own router to one of the existing router's LAN ports and simply broadcast your own wireless network, using any wireless security protocol, SSID and password you want.

You would need to be sure to disable DHCP on the new router, as there is already a DHCP server on the network and you want to avoid IP address conflicts.

You would essentially only want the new router to act as an additional access point.

Comment: Thank you very much!